# SQL concatenation of Identical rows

Tags: sql, concatenation, string-concatenation, summary

I have a Row that prints out all contact information (Name, Industry, sitename etc...) for a client. There are 2 fields "Phone" and "Email Address" both of these are accessed by a rec_ID. 1 for Phone and 2 for email. So when run it will print out two identical rows of information. The first row has a null value for phone but prints the email the second instance of this row has the phone number but is null for the email. So I made a summary line but it is only reading the first row and copying that to the summary line. I need to find away to be able to print both email and phone number on the same line. I dont know if the summary line is necessary or if theres a better way to do it. I just dont know how to access that second line since it is the same as the first line its just run twice. I am using BIDS SSRS with predefined fields and tables in which I can not manipulate.

current output looks like:

```
TicketID: Name: Phone: Email: 
  123       Ben    555   
  123       Ben          Ben@mail.com
```

I want it to combine and output as such:

```
 TicketID: Name: Phone: Email: 
  123       Ben    555   Ben@mail.com
```

Comment: You should probably use subselect for retrieving phone number in one row together with e-mail. What query are you using now?

Comment: Which flavor of SQL (Oracle, SQL-Server, etc.)?  Also, please show your current query, what data it returns and what you want it to return.  Adding that to your question will make it much easier to understand what you want and how to best do it.

Comment: Please format your question What is your query that you tried and expected result from your table

Comment: Im using Microsoft Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

You can create two derived queries (1 for phones and 1 for emails) and join them together using a full join. An example exists below:

```
declare @test table(ticketid int,rec_id int, name varchar(20), phone varchar(20), email varchar(20))

insert into @test(ticketid, rec_id, name, phone, email) values (1, 1, 'Ben', '123456', null)
insert into @test(ticketid, rec_id, name, phone, email) values (1, 2, 'Ben', null, 'test@test.com')
insert into @test(ticketid, rec_id, name, phone, email) values (2, 3, 'Ben', null, 'test2@test.com')

select phones.phone, emails.email, emails.name from 
(select ticketid, 
        rec_id, 
        phone, 
        email,
        name
from @test 
where phone is not null) phones
full join 
    (select 
        ticketid, 
        rec_id, 
        phone, 
        email,
        name
    from @test 
    where email is not null) emails
on phones.ticketid = emails.ticketid
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest way to do this is to group the results and pick the not null fields.

```
select TicketID, Name, max(Phone) as Phone, max(Email) as Email
from YourTable
group by TicketID, Name
```